# Photos and videos not showing up on Windows in DCIM\Camera for Galaxy S21 Ultra

Tags: usb, file-transfer, windows, usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-21

Often I can't see any files in DCIM\Camera on my Galaxy S21 Ultra running Android 12.  Last night it worked and I copied multiple GB of videos / images, then it didn't work the next times I tried.

I've tried the following steps:

- Rebooting phone and computer
- Uninstalling the phone in Device Manager under Portable Devices
- Updating the USB driver using the ... menu in Smart Switch
- Updating the USB driver by downloading directly from Samsung
- Enabling USB Debugging mode and rebooting (this made things worse so I had to turn it off)
- Changing the USB mode to charge only and then back to "USB for file transfer"
- Changing the USB mode to "USB for image transfer"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was able to be solved using the Files app to move a bunch of images to another folder and move those off the device and then the DCIM\Camera folder worked again (read online that the image count can be a cause of this issue).

As a tip, pressing and holding and dragging allows selecting a bunch of files relatively easily.